# How to change Wordpress language conditionally?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there any way to change the Wordpress language conditionally? I mean let's say we have a variable `$theme_lang` and if that is equal to something, change the language across the theme. 
Here's the code:

```
if($theme_lang == 'de'){
 //everything goes here in German
}
```

In short, I want to avoid a separate installation for another language. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change Wordpress language globally in *wp-config.php* with the `WPLANG` constant like this:

```
define( 'WPLANG', 'de_DE' );
```

Though if you want to change language section per section you can't use this. You should better go for a multilingual plugin, [there is many of them](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?type=term&q=multilingual), some paid (WPML), some free (qTranslate, Multilingual Press...).

Then in your template you can switch the plugin language constant on some section to force a language on content.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, `WPLANG` constant is no more needed with the latest version. Also it doesn't effect when I use it. What I mean to say is, I want to change the language conditionally within my code.

Comment: Well `WPLANG` should affect the language used for gettext - so it will change the language for gettext functions only (things like `<?php _e('text'); ?>`). What type of content are you trying to have in multilingual? Is that a post?

Comment: I have wrapped the things in `_e` and it works if I change the language from settings but not from`WPLANG`. I want to display some dynamic content. let's say if something equals to something then the complete language should be changed..

Comment: Where did you changed the value of `WPLANG`? If it's before the _wp-settings.php_ include it would be overwritten.

Comment: Could you try `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');` ?